# Mails sent from the command line not appearing in inbox or spam folder

Tags: email, postfix

I sent some test mails using the command line. In the log I can see that `status = sent`, but I am not getting any emails in my inbox or spam folder.

```
Oct 11 15:51:01 ip-10-0-1-80 postfix/local[20606]: 724AB6D5B: to=<root@localhost>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to go to the root user's mailbox, not your user's (unless you're root). Switch to root:

```
sudo -i su
```

...and check mail:

```
mail
```

Cheers,

OJ